# Most people vs. most of the people

Tags: articles

I'm preparing for academic IELTS by writing some essays and then correcting those using a grammar correction app.

In the following sentence,

> Since most of the people tend to concentrate in cities these days, ...

The app suggests using "most people" instead of "most of the people".
Is this critical or is it just a minor flaw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Most people" is used to make general statements about humankind.

> Most people have two eyes.

If you say "most of the people" I'd expect you to tell me which particular group of people you are talking about.

> Most of the people at my workplace wear jeans.

As usual "the" means that the noun is "determined"  So the group of people is known to the speaker and the listener.

In your case, you seem to be making a general point about humankind, so delete the word "the".

Comment: Does this apply to words other than people? Do they have to be countable?